# Can I reference environment variables from an Apache ActiveMQ Artemis broker.xml?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, activemq-artemis

As the title says, if I have a variable defined in the same scope as the ActiveMQ Artemis process, can I access it from the configuration XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot reference environment variables directly from the broker's configuration XML.

However, you *can* use the values of environment variables to set Java "system properties" in `etc/artemis.profile` and then reference the system properties in the XML. For example, if you had an environment variable named `MY_ENV_VAR` then you could reference that variable to set a system property by adding a line like this at the end of `artemis.profile`:

```
JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -DmyEnvVar=$MY_ENV_VAR"
```

Then in the XML you can use that system property via the syntax `${myEnvVar}`.

You can read more about referencing system properties in the XML in the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-server.html#configuration-files).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the ActiveMQ Classic and using the same solution. But in AMQ-Classic I had to use the $ACTIVEMQ_SSL_OPT environment variable to pass my custom variable with `-DmyEnvVar=$MY_ENV_VAR`. And used my custom varibale in activemq.xml as `myEnv="${myEnvVar}"`
It works too.